# Choosing point from polygon (featurecollection) in Google Earth Engine

Tags: polygon, google-earth-engine, point, features

I want to get points from the polygon. If I just use function (randomPoints), each polygon does not have the same numbers (50) of points so I want to find the point from each polygon, but my code is not working.

```
var points = polygons.map(function(f){
   var poly=f.geometry();
    return ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(poly,50);

 });



Map.addLayer(points )
print(points )
```

Answer (score 1):

When you map over a featurecollection and return a featurecollection, you will need to flatten the collection to make it a featurecollection of features.

```
var points = polygons.map(function(f){
   var poly= f.geometry();
    return ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(poly,50);
 }).flatten();
```

[Link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/1372e685a6a24c9cf1ba48c402293da5)

Comment: Thank you about it